# Check if command line argument is already used

Tags: python

I'm trying to check reverse lookup of IP address (argument). and then write the result to txt file.
 How I can check if the IP address (argument) is already registered in the file? If so, I need to get out of the script.

My script:

```
import sys, os, re, shlex, urllib, subprocess 

cmd = 'dig -x %s @192.1.1.1' % sys.argv[1]

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

# Convert to list of str lines
out = out.decode().split('\n')

# Only write the line containing "PTR"
with open("/tmp/test.txt", "w") as f:
 for line in out:
    if "PTR" in line:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: What do you mean by “registered in the file”?

Comment: @2ps: I think OP means the IP is present in the file on which he is writting the content

Comment: The script write the dig result to txt file. I want to check if the argument IP is write inside the log. If so, I need to get out of the script

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too large you could do:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
if ip in content:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Now if the file is big and you want to avoid possible memory problems you could use [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) like so:

```
import mmap
with open("file.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    if mm.find(ip) != -1: 
        sys.exit(0)
```

The `mmap.find(string[, start[, end]])` is well documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap.find).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
otherIps = [line.strip() for line in open("<path to ipFile>", 'r')]
theIp = "192.168.1.1"
if theIp in otherIps:
    sys.exit(0)
```

`otherIps` contains a `list` of the ip addresses on `ipFile`, then you need to check if `theIp` is already on `otherIps`, if so, exit the script.